# Representability of the Weil restriction reference and proof

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

Proposition 2 of 7.6 of Néron Models [BLR] provides a sufficient condition for the representability of a Weil restriction $R_{S'/S}(X')$. The theorem is attributed to Grothendieck.

> Is there an original reference for this theorem?

I also have a naive question about understanding representability of the Weil restriction along the following lines.

Let $f:C\to D$ be a functor between small categories, then $f$ induces a functor $f^*:\hat D\to\hat C$, where $\hat C=[C^{\mathrm{op}},\mathbf{(set)}]$ is the category of presheaves, defined by $f^*(\mathbf Y)(X)=\mathbf Y(f(X))$.

On the other hand, since $\hat C$ is the free cocompletion and $\hat D$ is cocomplete, there is a unique functor $\hat f:\hat C\to\hat D$ such that $\hat f\circ y_C=y_D\circ f$ ($\hat f$ is explicitly defined by some limit). In fact, using that hom commutes with the right kind of limits, we have an adjunction $\hat f \dashv f^*$.

Now if $f^*$ is itself isomorphic to a functor $\hat g$ for some $g:D\to C$, we may iterate the process with $g$ instead of $f$ to obtain another functor $f_* = g^* : \hat C\to \hat D$ and an adjunction $\hat g\dashv f^*$, so a triple $\hat f \dashv f^* \dashv f_*$.

If $C$ and $D$ are in particular slice (= comma) categories $C=S_{X}$ and $C=S_Y$ of the categories of schemes and $u:X\to Y$ is a morphism, then composition of the structural morphism with $u$ defines a functor $f=f_u:C\to D$ 'restriction of the base'. Conversely, there is a functor $g:D\to C$ given by $T\leadsto T\times_Y X$ 'extension of the base' or 'base change'. In fact my guess is that $\hat g = f^*$, so there is a functor $g^*=f_*$ which is then called 'Weil restriction $R_u=R_{X/Y}$'.

Now I may be wrong about this, but it occurs to me that if the Weil restriction $f^*$ of a representable object is itself representable this implies that $f_*$ is itself of the form $\hat h$, and therefore we can add a functor $h^*=f^{**}$ to the triple obtain $\hat f \dashv f^* \dashv f_*\dashv f^{**}$. So one could ask the following question: *what good properties of a functor $f^*:\hat C\to\hat D$ guarantee that it is of the form $\hat g$?*

Also, perhaps even more naive: how do certain niceness conditions on $u$ translate into properties of $\hat f\dashv f^*\dashv f_* \dashv f^{**} \dashv \cdots$ with $f=f_u$.

> So, here are some questions:
>
> - Does all of this sound correct?
> - Is there a better name for $f^{**}$?
> - In what contexts have these ideas been explored?
> - Is there a more general statement of type $(\exists g)(f^*=\hat g$) which implies the representability of the Weil restriction?

Comment: Too many questions, let me just answer the first one. The original reference is Grothendieck's Bourbaki lecture no. 221 (May 1961), *Techniques ... IV: les schemas de Hilbert*, §4 c. Note that Grothendieck denotes the Weil restriction by $\prod_{S'/S}(X'/S')$.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I'll check it out right away! Do you think I should split up the remaining questions?